# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens

Tags: tomcat9

I am getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens` while uploading files to the server. I am using tomcat 9 with openjdk 11 on ubuntu server.

I have created the application using struts2.5.

The error that I received is:

```
Jun  8 09:33:22: Error parsing HTTP request header
Jun  8 09:33:22: Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
Jun  8 09:33:22: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:416)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:260)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
Jun  8 09:33:22:     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I am running the application on tomcat and Using a SSL certificate also.

I have configured the server.xml upto best of my knowledge. Here is my server.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!-- APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
<!--
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />

-->
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="443"/>
    
  <!-- The max post size is nearly equal to 10 MB -->
  <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="150" 
    maxPostSize="-1" maxHttpHeaderSize ="1048576" maxSavePostSize="-1"
    port="443" keystoreFile="conf/screen.evelynlearning.com.keystore" keystorePass="evelyn"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" URIEncoding="UTF-8" relaxedQueryChars="[\]^`{|}"/>
    

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    <Host name="screen.evelynlearning.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context path="" docBase="RAT" debug="0" privileged="true" />
        <Context docBase="/etc/tomcat9/Catalina/screen.evelynlearning.com/imageresource" path="imageresource"/>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    </Host>
     <Host name="dashboardfortl.evelynlearning.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context path="" docBase="Dashboard-3.3" debug="0" privileged="true" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    </Host>
    
     <Host name="knowledgepark.evelynlearning.com"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context path="" docBase="EvelynKnowledgePark-1" debug="0" privileged="true" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

When I upload files larger then 40 KB, then the files are not uploaded and the request object is dropped. If the files are smaller than 40 KB, then the files are uploaded. I am not sure why is this happening.

I am also using **SSL** and I am using **https** while accessing my site. All other functionality is working correctly on **https**. It is just that the I am not receiving the uploaded files when I get this error.

If anyone knows about this, please do help. I have been searching for this for a few days now.

Edit:

I am using Apache Tomcat/9.0.31 version of tomcat 9 on Ubuntu.

Edit 2:
I found that the application is throwing this exception when submitting a form on https. When I use same application without the SSL, then everything works fine. Apart from form submission everything on SSL works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably you are trying to connect through HTTPS to a plain HTTP connector (i.e. you use `https://localhost:80`). More recent version of Tomcat 9.0 than the one you are using show the invalid HTTP method in the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am not explicitly using any port to connect to the site. I am using default port for https which is 443. And I am using the public ip address to connect to it from outside the network. So, lets suppose my ip is 111.111.111.10, then I am connecting in this manner https://111.111.111.10/ApplicationName